# BigCommerce - Stencil - Ajax quick-view related products

Tags: ajax, bigcommerce

I'm trying to add related products to the quick-view modal.  I'm unable to load data for {{product.related_products}} I've tried adding yaml to define the desired data in quick-view.html

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that resource is yet available to the quick view modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like front-matter only works on top level pages and not components:

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/using-yaml-front-matter

> You can use front matter to specify attributes at the tops of pages in your /templates/pages/ subdirectory. However, you cannot use front matter to accomplish this on pages in the
>   /templates/components/ or /templates/layout/ subdirectories.